# Error connection refused while starting angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, chrome-debugging

Someday I was creating projects in Angular 4 and I want to do this again but on a newer version of Angular.

What I did:

1.) Installation of Visual Studio Code.

2.) Installation of Nodejs:
Node version is 10.15.1
Npm version is 6.4.1

3.) Installation of Angular CLI by "npm install -g @angular/cli" commend.

4.) I created new project by cmd and build him by ng serve. After all I launch him by localhost:4200 in my browser - everything was great.

5.) Installation of Debugger for Chrome.

6.) Changing default port from 8080 to 4200.

7.) Launching the project and I am getting ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

I tried also launch project on default port (4200) - the same situation (error connection).

What did I wrong? I forgot about something or I don't know something important?
I don't have any warnings or errors in console/logs.
What I should do, to have my project in Chrome browser under localhost:PORT?

Comment: I think you are serving your project on 4200 and you are using the same port for the debugger too and hence the connection is refused

Comment: But I tried change port from 4200 to different in launch.json and it didn't help.

Comment: Try using ng serve --port 5200

Comment: Like I said, I tried and worked but I want to use chrome debugger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this issue.
I can work with my application in two modes Launch or Attach.
In the first case (**launch**) I had to do:
1.) I added configuration in launch.json for launch mode like below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Details:
Most important is set good port in url. I had to set 4200 port because it's default port for ng serve (https://angular.io/cli/serve).
2.) I had to compile my application. I can do it via terminal in Visual Studio Code like below:
[image]
or I can do it via cmd like below:
[image]
3.) I installed "Debugger for Chrome" extention via marketplace like below:
[image]
After this 3 steps I added some breakpoint and could run (F5) my application in debug mode [image] like below:
[image]
In the second case (**attach**) I had to do:
1.) I added configuration in launch.json for attach mode like below:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
        }
    ]
}
```

2.) I installed "Debugger for Chrome" extention via marketplace. 
3.) I set remote debugging ("--remote-debugging-port=9222") for Chrome application like below:
[image]
Details:
Path for my Chrome "target": 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --remote-debugging-port=9222
4.) I started that Chrome which had remote debugging in path of "target".
Be careful!
If you have Chrome icon on taskbar, you have to add remote debugging newly!(it's stupid I know).
5.) After this 4 steps I added some breakpoint and could run (F5) my application (before it, you have to compile project - step 2 in first example!) [image] in debug mode and everything works.

Now when I have to work with angular project I am compiling project via VSCode or cmd, I am starting Chrome in remote debugging on localhost:4200 and creating some front-end. When something is wrong, I am launching attach via VSCode and I can debug.